# Infinite scrolling text per line in paragraph

Tags: html, css, web, css-animations

I have a paragraph with around 20 lines. I want each of those lines to repeat itself after 1 scroll is completed. For example:

Let's say I had a line in a paragraph that is as follows:

1,2,3,4,

I would like the line to scroll horizontally on the screen (which I achieved), but I also want the 1 to come after the 4 after a single scroll has completed.

I got the horizontal scroll to work, but the sentences don't repeat.

I have each sentence in a span which is either bar_content1 or bar_content2. This is so I can have every other sentence go in a different direction.

I've tried to take advantage of the ::before function but I can't seem to get it working.

I included an image below of the logic of my final idea.

**Note**: HTML included in this question isn't what is in my project due to privacy reasons. That being said, the code is formatted the same way.

[image]

```css
.bar_content2 {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  animation: move2 100s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes move2 {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}

.bar_content1 {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  animation: move1 100s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes move1 {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}


/* Animate each line in the paragraph */

p {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* Prevent line breaks */
}

p::before {
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  /* Start from the right side */
  animation: scrollText 20s linear infinite;
  /* Adjust the duration as needed */
}

@keyframes scrollText {
  0% {
    left: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  /* Move to the left, creating the interlacing effect */
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span class="bar_content1">1,2,3,4,</span>
  <span class="bar_content2"> 5,6,7,8, </span>
</p>
```

Comment: Please post your HTML as well

Comment: Thanks. I have converted your code into a snippet that can be run in your question now. Is that working as you expect it to?  Is anything missing?  What have you tried so far to get your intended behavior working?

Comment: @ChrisBarr Yes very close. The horizontal scroll is how I would like it, but I want the lines to infinitely repeat one after another so it looks like one big sentence (if that make sense). I tried using these lines of code, but didn't get the results intended `p::before {
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fadeInOut 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes fadeInOut {
  0%, 100% { opacity: 1; }
  50% { opacity: 0; }
}`

Comment: Is there a `<p>` tag missing in your HTML?

Comment: Sorry, that's my bad. Yes the whole thing should be within a p tag. I can't include my actual html due to privacy, but as an example that is what it should look like.

Comment: What I'm trying to get at here is that you please edit your question to contain all the necessary information and code needed for someone to try and help you out. Once all that in in place someone can try to help you out. When writing a question you need to make it quick and easy for someone to see what you are currently doing, what you want to do differently, and see all of the code that is relevant.

Comment: Gotcha. Thank you. Still new to the platform. I'll edit my question to make it easier to understand

Comment: @ChrisBarr Thank you for sticking with me... Updated the question and hopefully it's easier to understand

Comment: Can you a JavaScript for this? I think I could work up a solution, but it would be MUCH easier if you used something like [GreenSock](https://greensock.com/).

Comment: I've never heard of GreenStock before (I am pretty new to this). Is it easy to learn/grasp?

Comment: GreenSock is pretty easy. They have great docs and tutorials. What makes this tricky is that don't know the width of the sentence and you have to use 100%, it means there will be a gap in the timing. You need to scroll the entire sentence off the page before it can come back on. Which means you have to go from 100% to -100%. Everything from 0 to -100% will be blank. JS would make this MUCH easier.

Comment: Do you mind giving me an example of what the JS code could look like?

Comment: The `1,2,3,4` you're referring to (and presenting in the code) have nothing to do with the [idea logic image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsJp4.png) you provided. I think you got your task completely wrong. The image you provided is nothing else but an ***infinite carousel***, with duplicated first and last items for the *next / prev* seamless transition, and the snapback offset to allow for *infinite* scrolling.

Answer (score -1):

Now I understand a little better after your updates which added the code and the image to describe the effect you want.  You basically want a carousel. A quick search online shows lots of options.  This page in particular has some good stuff: https://css-tricks.com/css-only-carousel/

I've modified the last example on that page here, which makes use of a JS library called Flickity: https://flickity.metafizzy.co/

I have never personally used Flickety before, it it seems pretty good from what I can see, and it's simple, and it requires no other dependencies. It may not be perfect, but I think this gets you like 90% of the way there!

Note that FLickety has a lot of options you can read about here: https://flickity.metafizzy.co/options.html and I've set a few of them for you in the `data-flickity` HTML attribute.  Change those as you need.

```css
.carousel {
  background: #EEE;
}

.carousel-cell {
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  background: #8C8;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.min.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<div class="carousel"
  data-flickity='{
    "autoPlay": 1500,
    "selectedAttraction": 0.01,
    "pauseAutoPlayOnHover": false,
    "friction": 0.15,
    "wrapAround": true,
    "draggable": false,
    "prevNextButtons": false,
    "pageDots": false,
    "contain": true
  }'>
  <div class="carousel-cell">1, 2, 3, 4</div>
  <div class="carousel-cell">5, 6, 7, 8</div>
  <div class="carousel-cell">9, 10, 11, 12</div>
</div>
```